# ios drag and drop library

Tags: ios, ipad

I am looking for any libraries that exist to allow drag and drop functionality like the tracks in Garage Band on iPad. Does anybody know of good library (open source or commercial) that exist.

Comment: I eneded up writing my own but thanks for the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Oblong we created a self-contained iOS Drag and Drop library that can work across arbitrary views, and have made it public on github:

https://github.com/Oblong/OBDragDrop

If you find it useful or have specific areas of enhancements you need, go ahead and let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I have also made my own static library (I had no idea about OBDragDrop)

https://github.com/jmos/JCMDragging (compile with ARC)

The library mirrors common UIKit patterns so the bulk of the interfaces are actually categories on UIKit classes:

- Dragging events are handled and forwarded by UIResponder
- Dragging events are delivered according to hitTest:withDrag: and pointInside:withDrag:
- Data transfer uses [UIPasteboard draggingPasteboard] and [UIResponder drag:/drop:]

The only concrete class is the gesture recogniser. There are no managers or initialisation.

Have a look at the sample project to see how to use it.

**EDIT:** I have added a readme file now.